# Stack 2 words on top of each other

Tags: css

I have 2 words in a circular submit button that I want stacked on top of each other instead of side by side. I tried "word-wrap:break-word;", but this coding is width and height contingent.

I'd rather not create an image for the submit button as I'm sure there is a way to achieve this with CSS. Thank you for any help!

**It's a Mail Chimp sign up form**

HTML

```
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Get It!" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
```

CSS

```
.button {
    font-family: 'Lobster', Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    letter-spacing: .03em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f8a8a1;
    border: 2px solid #f8a8a1;
    padding: 0em 0.3em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    height:74px;
    width:74px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -1em 0em;
    line-height:1em;
}
```

Comment: Show me your CSS and HTML

Answer (score 1):

Setting `word-spacing` equal to the width of the container will do this for you.

```
button {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 200px;
    word-spacing: 200px;        
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2y4m78k/

Comment: I tried this method but it didn't work. However, I was able to get it to work by increasing the font size and adjusting the padding for the text. Thank you!

Comment: When I added the "word-spacing", it didn't stack the two words, but instead just increased the space between the two words. I imagine the container is much bigger than the button width in this instance.

Comment: @greatwanderer When I said container I was referring to the text container, in my example it's the button. Set word-spacing equal to the width of the button. Post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: I posted the HTML and CSS.

Comment: My solution doesn't appear to work with inputs. Changing your input element to a button would make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `br` tag in it: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yp9qkn7q/1/)

`<button>Stack<br>words</button>`

Comment: He asked for an CSS fix, not a HTML.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<button class="myButton">
    <p class="word-one">TopWord</p> 
    <p class="word-two">BottomWord</p>
</button>
```

CSS

```
.myButton{
   position:relative;
   width:50px; /*whatever dimensions you want*/
   height:50px;
}

.word-one{
   position:absolute;
   top:0px;
   left:10px;
}

.word-two{
   position:absolute;
   top:20px;
   left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use CSS over HTML, and do not want it to be width & height contingent, the only way that I can think of doing this is using the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

One thing I am not too sure about is how to center those elements, so you will have to play around a bit

```css
#submit {
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

#submit:before {
  content: "Top Row";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#submit:after {
  content: "Bottom Row";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="submit"></button>
```